# TFS: Deny Check-in permission for a user on one group

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have assigned permissions to users on Group Level in TFS. I have a user who is assigned on more than one group and is allowed to check-in code in both groups. I want to allow user to check-in code changes in Group A but not in Group B.

I will be thankful to you if you can guide me how i can do this.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

No, we cannot achieve that.

In general you should try to avoid having users in multiple groups as in TFS **deny** always wins.

That means if you set `check in` as **Deny** for **Group B**, then all the users in Group B will not be able to check in changes even though the user in other groups have the **Allow** permission.

> **Permissions**
>
> It combines the permissions from all the users groups.
>
> If the user is denied access to anything they still can't access it
>   even if they are given access to it elsewhere.
>
> If the user is given access to something in any group they will have
>   access to it (unless of course something else denies them).
>
> If there's no explicit allow or deny in any of the users groups, they
>   will be denied access.

Answer (score 0):

I think that people in GroupA work in part of source control and GropB in another. If so You have to enable check-in policies in both groups and instead configure source countrol foder or branch security policies in order to anable or not chech-in or even other features on any group.

To do that:

1. Go in source control explorer
2. Rigth click on folder or branch: Advanced->Security
3. Enjoy!